# Store data in linux local directory using flume

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, flume

is it possible to get the data from oracle using flume and store it in Linux local folders, not in hdfs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using "File Roll Sink" you can store streaming data to local system. But Flume can't use to ingest data from any RDMS tool.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about Oracle, but writing to local filesystem is implemented by [File Roll Sink](http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#file-roll-sink).